# filesystem read/write: Is this a race condition?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
import {appendFile, readFile} from 'fs'

// Read data from an Apache server's access log
readFile(
  '/var/log/apache2/access_log',
  {encoding: 'utf8'},
  (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error('error reading!', error)
      return
    }
    console.info('success reading!', data)
  }
)

// Concurrently, write data to the same access log
appendFile(
  '/var/log/apache2/access_log',
  'New access log entry',
  error => {
    if (error) {
      console.error('error writing!', error)
    }
  })
```

Is it guaranteed that the read will complete before the `appendFile` writes to the filesystem, or is it possible that my data might get appended before the `readFile` completes, so that `readFile` returns my newly-appended data?

Comment: well what did you find

Comment: @epascarello Sorry? My question is if this is a race condition, and I was hoping to get input from the experts on SO. By their nature, race conditions are hard to find, and I wouldn't necessarily be able to observe one by running this code.

Comment: Read should happen first. file system operations should be issued in-order, I think the underlying system calls will all be in the same order too. I also think that due to permissions reasons (each access uses different permissions) Node must independently allocate file handles. So no race should happen.

Comment: Thanks @Catalyst. That happens to be the case here because both the read and write are operating on the same file, right? Or would it also be true for two reads to two *different* files?

Comment: Answering this myself: reading from two different files is not stable, and indeed has a race condition. Demo: https://gist.github.com/bcherny/0f778173246356d8467112c0365b10a0

Comment: @bcherny exactly. you issue the requests in-order and the OS does them out of order due to contention or whatever mayhem is happening out there. Could be lots of things ranging from process contention to availability based on the file system & driver (imagine one file in a really slow network drive).

Comment: @bcherny which raises an important distinction. Suppose you issue request 1) with readwrite permissions, and request 2) with read permissions. I suppose it is possible that with some filesystems a process could have the file write-locked and therefore request 1) is blocked while request 2) functions as expected.
So yep. unstable :(.

Answer (score 1):

Trying this out with a quick test, it really is unstable:

https://gist.github.com/bcherny/029473f21833a73126d2e1dce53f2a6a